# Python tkinter can not edit a new window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create and edit a new window but i can not show the labels

Here is my code:

```
from random_words import RandomWords
import requests
import urllib.request
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse as url
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *

def update(new):
    var.set(new)

    pencere.update_idletasks()
def yeni1():
    pencere2 = Tk()
    pencere2.geometry("1000x600+300+300")

    pencere2.tk_setPalette("black")
    baslik = pencere2.title("Tesekkürler")
    var2 = StringVar()
    var2.set("""
DİKKAT! Bu program Hacknology tarafından kodlanmıştır ve izinsizce paylaşılması yasaktır. İyi kullanımlar dilerim.""")

    var3 = StringVar()
    var3.set("""THX""")
    etiket2 = Label(pencere2, textvariable=var2,
                               fg="blue",
                               bg="#000000",
                               font="Helvetica 25 bold")
    etiket2.pack(side=TOP)
    etiket3 = Label(pencere2, textvariable=var3,
                    fg="orange",
                    bg="#000000",
                    font="Helvetica 25 bold")
    etiket3.pack(side=TOP)
    mainloop()
def kodlar():
    print("Hello world")
pencere = Tk()
pencere.geometry("800x600+100+100")
##yeni_pencere_buton= Button(text="ODIN", command=yeni)
##yeni_pencere_buton.pack()
buton1 = Button(text="Teşekkür ve Hakkında", command=yeni1)
buton1.pack()
baslik = pencere.title("ODIN GIRIS")
var = StringVar()
var.set("ODIN PROJECT ")
pencere.tk_setPalette("black")
etiket = Label(pencere,textvariable=var,
               fg="blue",
               bg="#000000",
               font="Helvetica 25 bold")
etiket.pack(side=TOP)
```

But I see only dark screen, there is no labels as I edit it. If i add "master", that doesn't works either. What can/must i do?Thanks for your help

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question rather than linking to another site. Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yeah, but i don't know how to add a code. I'm kinda newie on stackof

Comment: @hckn0 you just copy/paste it into the text area where you wrote your question. Once it's there, you can highlight it and press CTRL + K to format it. Since you are new, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ah. thx. I added the code. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your full code, I don't know how you see anything...

There's nothing that runs and several things wrong here.

`mainloop` never gets run. This is needed to render the window. You have it in the `yeni1` function, but that never runs. It's assigned to `buton1` `Button` widget with no parent widget.

If you want to get your code running, all you need to do is add `pencere.mainloop()` to the bottom of your script.